# C# change location of controls inside FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel, flowlayoutpanel

I am using `flowLayoutPanel` to have relative location controls.
I would like to change the location of control inside the `flowLayoutPanel`.
when I say location, I dont mean control1 before control2 or something like that - I mean that if I got 2 controls, lets say `label` and `comboBox` - the `comboBox`'s height is 21, the `label`'s height is 13 and the `flowLayoutPanel`'s height is 21 also. I want to put the `label` in the vertical middle of the `flowLayoutPanel` - ((21-13)/2) from top. I dont want something specific for vertical middle I want general solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also set the top margin of the label to (containerHeight-labelHeight)/2

Comment: Worked like a charm, I forgot about the margin property.

Comment: Who da Man?  You da Man!  This worked great.  For anyone else working with this, the margin has to be copied to a variable, modified and then set back.

Answer (score 2):

The flow layout is not going to help: it just arranges all controls in a list, adjusting their position to fit in the panel. You can create subgroups by putting controls in a table within the flow layout, or just use a table for maximum control.

Comment: How exactly can I set the location of control inside tableLayoutPanel? I cant do it inside tableLayoutPanel too..

Comment: I do like the idea of using a TableLayoutPanel - you can set control positions and even dimensions just by setting the dimensions of columns/rows. For a full GUI, it takes a little more planning than placing everything into a FlowLayoutPanel, but I think the rewards are worth it.

Comment: Right - you can always dock the controls within each cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int cIndex = this.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(Button1);
    int bIndex = this.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(Button1);

    this.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(Button1, bIndex);
    this.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(Button2, cIndex);
```